# How to pass an argument from a data table to a modal in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to pass an argument from data table and pushing the values to a modal in a flutter web project. I tried reading a few topics but I'm struggling to find a solution.
Here is how am trying to pass the data to the modal, which I don't think is correct!-but am newbie in flutter. The solution works for me when I route to the page instead of a modal.

```js
previewEstate(element) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return PreviewEstateModal();
      // Navigator.pushReplacement(
      //   context,
      //   PageRouteBuilder(
      //     pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => PreviewEstateModal(),
      //     transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
      //     settings: RouteSettings(arguments: element),
      //   ),
      // );
    },
  );
}
```

The commented part of my code works if I route to that page i.e am able to receive the route setting argument, but I want to do this by using a modal. **What could I be doing wrong?**

Comment: you can pass your data by both model argument or routing settings. But routing setting is most preferable.

Comment: @JahidulIslam, how can i pass that please, that is the problem am facing

Comment: you can initialize element in PreviewEstateModal class and pass by arguments

Comment: this is how I have tried to initialize the element within the build of the PreviewEstateModal but the element value is logged as null

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final EstateSearch estate =
         ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as EstateSearch;
print(estate.name);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with following code

```
previewEstate(element) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return PreviewEstateModal(estate: element); // here you pass the arguments
      
    },
  );
}
```

In your `PreviewEstateModal`, initialize the argument(`EstateSearch`)

```
class PreviewEstateModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final EstateSearch estate;

  PreviewEstateModal({this.estate});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          '${estate}',/// initilize estate property
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```